# Get last 5 rows by Attribute, postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an event table associated with users
I would like to know if it possible to write an sql query, to select  user who create event, and the last 3 events had the status 'canceled'

> not count() where status = 'canceled', only where last 3 rows had status canceled

```
Select u.* from users AS u
Right Join events as e ON e.user_id = u.id
WHERE {last 3 rows have e.status = 'canceled'}
Order by e.created_at
Group by u.id
```

EVENTS table:

```
user_id, status, created_at
1, 'canceled', 2017-04-21
1, 'finished', 2017-04-20
1, 'finished', 2017-04-19
1, 'canceled', 2017-04-18
1, 'canceled', 2017-04-17
2, 'canceled', 2017-04-21
2, 'canceled', 2017-04-20
2, 'canceled', 2017-04-19
2, 'finished', 2017-04-18
2, 'finished', 2017-04-17
```

Comment: please post some sample data and the expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the list of users using window functions.  Here is one method:

```
select e.user_id
from (select e.*,
             row_number() over (partition by e.user_id order by created_at desc) as seqnum
      from event e
     ) e
where seqnum <= 3 and e.status = 'canceled'
group by e.user_id
having count(*) = 3;
```

The query enumerates the events from the end and then counts the number that are canceled.

You can get additional user information by joining back to `users` (or using `in` or `exists`).

Comment: it will get only events with status = canceled? 
or it will get user_id who have last 3 canceled events?

Comment: @mikrafizik . . . This will return users whose last three events are canceled.  This checks that all three are canceled.  If only one needs to be canceled, remove the `having` clause.